# Geonetwork doesn´t load UI

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, user-interface, tomcat, geonetwork

I´m trying to install Geonetwork (both 3x and 4x) but the UI doesn´t load. I´m on Tomcat 9, Java 8, Postgres 12.
Installing from de WAR (https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/en/install-guide/installing-from-war-file.html) I got no errors, but on the dev panel from Chrome I got

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$injector/nomod?p0=gn
    at lib.js:20
    at lib.js:39
    at b (lib.js:38)
    at Object.module (lib.js:38)
    at gn_search_default.js:201
    at gn_search_default.js:318
lib.js?v=72bf9606a19b80dff9cd56fbe3f718a932f21aa3:39 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]
```

This err refers to Error:
Module Unavailable
Module 'gn' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Any guidance to resolve this? Thanks in advance.